# CSS : Transform rotate not working with span inner SVG tag

Tags: javascript, css, svg, chartist.js

I have created a Chart using Chartis.js. I liked that because its responsive. But the horizontal label looked not responsive, I tried to make the X-label rotate 90 degrees in order for preserve a lot of space, but its not working.

```
.ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
    transform:rotate(90deg) !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

Please help me, you can see my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/740yajof/

Comment: Can you cut down your example to just the markup that shows the issue and add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but it works pretty well when you move chartist scripts and styles to external resources. No need for `!important` or vendor prefix `-webkit-*`. I just added `transform-origin: left` to move the rotation anchor to the left (by default it's in the middle).

```
.ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/15zyq0q1/